# How to get specified content from indside a div

Tags: php, jquery, phpquery

How to **get content** (*a specified content*) from inside a **#div**.

I have form like:

```
<?php
require_once('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');
$key-one = $_POST['key01'];
$html = file_get_contents('http://google.com/search?q='.$key-one.'');
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
$result01 = pq('div#resultStats');
?>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="1.php">
    <input type="text" name="key01"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

I got result like:

```
About 1,570,000,000 results
```

But I only want

```
1,570,000,000
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP `str_replace`.

Assuming `$result01` displays `About 1,570,000,000 results`:

```
$result01 = str_replace("About ","",$result01);
$result01 = str_replace(" results","",$result01);
```

After these changes, `echo $result01` will display `1,570,000,000`.

Comment: It worked, thank you! :) Btw. While submitting text form, I mean two separated words like "one two" - Is there any chance I could submit the 'space' like "one+two" ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. If you're just replacing one string with another string, it should be no problem though.

Comment: EXAMPLE I type in the form "text1 text2", but I want to replace the 'space' between those two word into 'plus'- like "text1+text2"

Comment: Yes, then you would just do `str_replace(" ","+",$string);` Hope this helps :)

Comment: lawl, tbh. I did it the way you showed me before, and it worked `$01 = str_replace(" ","+",$01);` Big thanks! Your the boss.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use preg_replace,like

```
 $result = preg_replace('/[^\sa-z]/i', '', $string);
```

this removes every characters and whitespace from your string